# Timeout loading application on GAE using web2py

Tags: google-app-engine, web2py

I am uploading an app to GAE.  Through some experimentation I've found that if I don't include wsgihandler.py, the app loads very slowly.  It feels like it's looking for this file and them timing out.  Besides the slow loading, everything works perfectly without wsgihandler.py, so I want to know if there is a simple way to remove the references to the file.  I tried poking around the files, but it doesn't look like there are direct references.

Also, I asked before what I need at a minimum to get an application to work, and I found that I need:
web2py/app.yaml
web2py/gaehandler.py
web2py/VERSION
web2py/gluon/* (and subfolders, this is web2py)
web2py/applications/theoneappyouwanttodeploy/* (and subfolders)

Comment: Just want to point out this is no longer an issue.  I believe it was something on Google's end that changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pleas bring this up on the web2py group. This is odd since wsgihandler.py is not called by any other module. It is a handler not used on GAE.